# Finding the start and end time and dates for events in RStudio

Tags: r, datetime

I'm currently determining when upwelling events are occurring in Barrow Canyon, Alaska. I'm currently working with one year at a time to make it simple for me, as I'm also working with a very large dataset. For one year, 2010, there are around 8687 rows and several columns. I found that for upwelling events to occur; wind speeds need to be greater than 4 m/s and in the easterly direction while lasting for 12 or more hours. I've been successful in creating a code that finds the number of events for a given year.

```
# To determine # of times one appears 12 or more in a row

events <- c(Barrow$`Upwelling Events`)
consec_events <- rle(events)
num_consec_events <- sum(consec_events$length >= 12 & consec_events$values == 1)
cat("The number of events occurring 12 or more times in a row is:", num_consec_events, "\n")
```

Since I'm going to be comparing when upwelling events are occurring throughout the year to chlorophyll data (these are singular measurements made throughout the year, there are only ~ 600-700 rows, much smaller data), I need to be able to know when those events occurred. I've found one code that gives me a decent result, it gives me the number of events and the duration of each one, **but it does not give me the correlated/correct date**.

```
# Calculate whether each hour is part of an upwelling event

Barrow10$`Upwelling Events` <- Barrow10$`Wind Speed (m/s)` > 4 & Barrow10$`U Speed (m/s)` < 0

# Use `rle()` to identify runs of consecutive hours where upwelling occurred

upwelling_runs <- rle(Barrow10$`Upwelling Events`)

# Filter to only include runs of length 12 or greater where the value is TRUE (upwelling)

events <- data.frame(start_time = which(upwelling_runs$values & upwelling_runs$length >= 12), end_time = which(upwelling_runs$values & upwelling_runs$lengths >=12) + upwelling_runs$lengths[upwelling_runs$values & upwelling_runs$lengths >= 12] - 1)

# Convert start and end times from index values to actual times

events$start_time <- as.POSIXct(Barrow10$`Date & Time`[events$start_time], format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
events$end_time <- as.POSIXct(Barrow10$`Date & Time`[events$end_time], format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

# View the resulting list of events

View(events)
```

The inserted image is of the Excel file being used in RStudio. Columns Date & Time, Date, Time, Upwelling Events, Wind Speed (knots), U and V Speed (m/s), and Wind Angle (radians) have all been imported by me. All other cells were part of the original dataset downloaded. Start and End Time Columns were found using code; I'm not entirely too sure how accurate they are.

```
# To find the start and end time for the entire dataset

upwelling_times10 <- data.frame(start_time = Barrow10$`Date & Time`, end_time = Barrow10$`Date & Time`)
```

[Excel file used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EZ31N.png)

So, to find the start and end time for the upwelling events I've used the steps from # Calculate whether each hour is part of an upwelling event to # View the resulting list of events.

This is the result it gave me
[Results from the method used View(events)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lstx4.png)

I went through the first two columns, and the duration matches. But the date does not, the first upwelling event doesn't start till the mid of January. I am able to do this manually, but I would prefer not to go through 100,000 rows of data lol. A part of me wonders if what I did do can just be expanded to include the actual dates, but I'm not sure how to do that. **Overall, I'm trying to find a code to what I have now that will give me the specific date and time when events start and end.**

Thank you and all the best!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Hi Rach! A couple of things: 1. R is great, but it's not great for turning screenshots of spreadsheets into dataframes. If you want to show us sample data, use dput()!

Comment: 2. *but it does not give me the correlated/correct date* - can you elaborate on this